# Eslint precommit husky hook is not working as expected in create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, husky, lint-staged

Here's my configuration

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "hello-world",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.js": [
            "eslint --fix",
            "git add"
        ],
        "*.{js, jsx, json, html, css}": [
            "prettier --write",
            "git add"
        ]
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
        "husky": "^3.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "^9.2.0",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2"
    }
}
```

Now if I run that simply on the project like, `./node_modules/.bin/eslint .` , it is working as usual. Displays the changes that need to be made in the file but does not work as a pre-commit hook, prettier is working though. I still see that the eslint is running before every commit from the command line but I don't see any output presented. What could be the issue?

- Changing the line to, `eslint * --fix`, shows me fixes that are to be made in all files, even **.css** and **.md** files.
- Making it `eslint *.js --fix` tells me, no files matching the pattern were found.
- Even `eslint . --fix` doesn't work.

My folder structure is a simple create-react-app format, if that info is needed. [Full repo here](https://github.com/nobodyme/husky-precommit-hook-test)

I'll post the eslintrc and prettierrc file below as well,

**.prettierrc**

```
{
"singleQuote": false
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
"extends": ["react-app", "prettier"],
"plugins": ["prettier"],
"rules": {
"prettier/prettier": "error"
}
}
```

**Clarifications:**

1) I had to use the longer format version of prettier configuration, as opposed to `plugin:prettier/recommended` because I [ran into this error](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/103#issuecomment-425670176) while trying to have a separate prettierrc config file instead of having it inline in package.json

2) I had to use a lower version of eslint because the newer version was throwing random errors from a plain create-react-app and hence [had to downgrade it as discussed here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7284#issuecomment-509737634).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the **complete path** of the said linters in your `package.json`?

Something like this -

```
"lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,tsx}": [
        "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix",
        "git add"
    ],
    "*.{js, jsx, json, html, css}": [
        "./node_modules/.bin/prettier --write",
        "git add"
    ]
}
```

For me, it works as expected.

**[Reference Tutorial](https://digitalfortress.tech/tricks/lint-on-precommit-git-hook-made-easy/)**